# Sorting arraylist of array list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I waned to sort an array list of arraylist of numbers using java, so basically if I have the following arraylist:

```
arr.add(<1,0>)
arr.add(<0,3>)
arr.add(<2,1>)
arr.add(<2,2>)
```

the output should be:

```
<0,3>
<1,0>
<2,1>
<2,2>
```

The arraylist should be sorted according to the first key then the second key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  Use `lists.sort()`

The data

```
List<List<Integer>> lists =
        new ArrayList<>(List.of(List.of(0, 3), List.of(1, 0),
                List.of(2, 1), List.of(2, 2)));
```

Shuffle for demo

```
Collections.shuffle(lists);
```

- First compare the first element of each list and sort normally
- If two elements are equal, then sort based on the next element.

```
lists.sort(Comparator
        .comparing((List<Integer> lst) -> lst.get(0))
        .thenComparing(lst -> lst.get(1)));

lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[0, 3]
[1, 0]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
```